# phpStorm to reload running node.js server

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, phpstorm

So, im running phpstorm with nodejs plugin that runs a server on local machine.

But i have to manually restart the server each time i change something. It would be very nice if it could automatically restart it, kind of like automatic deployment or just working with php.

Is there any way i could configure that?

Comment: have you tried adding a new "node js" run configuration?

Comment: Yes, i did, it runs just as expected. Even debugger works fine.

Comment: From what i found it seems like i need to get webstorm instead, it has live edit feature for node. Still, there might be another solution to this.

Comment: what plugin are you running?

Comment: It's just called "NodeJS" from prefences-plugins-Install JetBrains plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can try using Live Edit for this (you need to install the corresponding plugin from a repository). See http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/08/live-edit-updates-in-webstorm-9/

Comment: So, this is webstorm exclusive feature? I seems that i cant do so with phpstorm.

Comment: This feature is available in PHPStorm as well, but you need to install Live Edit plugin from the repository